# Worklight 6.3 Migration- Getting this error while moving wlapps files to server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

•   FWLSE3210W: Environment: iphone of application "Project" version 1.0 has been deployed with a different version of the native MobileFirst SDK. Direct updates will no longer be available for existing clients with other versions of the MobileFirst SDK. To continue to use direct updates, increment the app version, publish it to the public app store, deploy to the server, and (optionally) block/notify older versions of the app to enforce customers to upgrade to the new version from the app store.

While some other application is working fine when building from same configured machine....

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error. It's a warning, and it means what... it means.

Your server is likely not of the same version as the Studio that generated the files. Make sure they are at the same version and try again.

The warning mentions the steps that you should follow.

Answer (score 0):

The  FWLSE3210W warning means that you didn't increment the version number when building it, which is required whenever native code changes - either due to a code change or due to using a newer version of Worklight Studio.